# Golf cart battery fuel gauge?

Tags: circuit-design, battery-operated

I've got a 10 segment golf cart fuel gauge meter that shows full at 36.9 volts and empty at 31.77 volts.

My problem that at full charge my golf cart battery reads 39.19V and when it won't go up an incline the batteries read 38.22V.

I thought maybe a voltage divider might work but the fuel gauge meter draws 9mA.

Any suggestions on a simple circuit that would pull my golf cart batter voltage level down in the range of the fuel gauge meter?  I'm really only looking to get an indication that the batteries are low, i.e. close to 38.22 volts.

The golf cart has six 6 volt batteries.

Comment: Is the problem that you want an accurate reading? Or is the problem that the gauge will be damaged if you put 39.19V into it (even though it may read 38.22V when you do so)? Because if accuracy is your concern then you are splitting hairs because voltage is not an accurate way to track battery capacity to begin with so just leave it as is. If damage is your concern but the gauge reads the same terminals that it draws power from there's no good way do *clamp* the voltage to not damage the meter without also draining the battery.

Comment: Yeah, I know it's not the most accurate way to track.  But currently the batteries never go below the 'full charge' point on the gauge, even when the golf cart doesn't move  making useless.   I was look to just shift the max voltage of the batteries down to the 'linear' portion of the gauge (between 36.9 and 31.77).

Comment: The issue is that 38.22V is nowhere near dead for a lead-acid battery. So it seems you're not really concerned about gauging battery capacity. In which case are you sure you want to do this? Because batteries decrease in voltage as they are discharged. On top of this, the voltage while the battery is supplying current (i.e. under load) is lower than when the battery is not supplying current.

Comment: Battery voltage not under load.   38.22 volts sitting still, full charge.  38.22 volts sitting still after not being able to climb small hill, i.e. need to be charge.

Comment: I was thinking maybe an Op Amp circuit to move the max 38.22 battery voltage down into the range (36.9 to 31.77) of the gauge just to give some slight indication of what's going on.

Comment: Regardless there's no good way to do this if the battery is drawing power through the same terminals that it is measuring. THe best way might just be a series resistor since you know it draws about 9mA. So pick a resistance where ~9mA will drop the voltage you want to remove.

Comment: So I should be spending my time redesigning a golf cart transmission and not trying to come up with a circuit that could shift a voltage from 38.22 volts to 36.9 volts?

Comment: What's the nominal voltage of this battery gauge? Are you sure it's just measuring the voltage, and not doing something fancier?

Comment: I'm not as certain about the transmission part as I was initially since I noticed you never actually said you were using lead-acid batteries. I was just assuming. Are your batteries lead-acid batteries? Because if they are then at 38.22V they should still be 90% full. But I also imagine if that were the case you would also be asking why you have to recharge your golf carts every 5 minutes. But your "full" and "empty" voltages are just way too close together.

Comment: My quick take on this is that you are solving the wrong problem. There is no way you can have such a small voltage difference between fully charged and empty unless the batteries are old or you have some other problem. You are saying that the full battery is 39.2, and at 38.2 it is functionally dead (unable to climb a hill). In my experience that does not comport with any known battery chemistry in common use.

Comment: So rather than try to help you with the problem you think you want to solve, I am kind of alarmed by what appears to me to be a much bigger and more serious problem. And also, if you solve the bigger and more serious problem, it may well be that the voltage problem will go away because the golf cart will be able to climb the hill even at 34 V or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

Likely, the lead-acid batteries have high internal impedance, or the connections to the batteries are corroded or loose.

This statement is based on the fact that at only **one volt** below full charge, they no longer can supply **sufficient current** to ascend a hill. This assumes that the voltage measurement has been made *open circuit*, i.e., while not drawing heavy current. To confirm this, *measure the battery voltage under load*, either going uphill or with a battery tester.

Comment: Under no load (golf cart stopped) when fully charged the six 6 volt batteries read 39.19 when fully charged and when very low (won't go up a hill) read 38.22 volts.  Under load when climbing hill the voltage reads 30.35 volts.  Under load on level ground the voltage is 32.19 volts.

Comment: So the issue is that a gauge measuring *open circuit, i.e., no-load condition*, is of not much use for you. It might have some relevance with *new* batteries, or not. A more accurate gauge would measure the voltage *under a temporary load*, lasting no more than a fraction of a second, since a heavy load drains the battery quickly and would overheat a resistor, Or just check the voltage with the existing gauge when going up a hill or ramp.

Answer (score 1):

I am making a speculation here. I think what your are indicating is that the battery voltage even when the cart cannot climb a hill, is beyond the range of the voltage gauge. Your question is how to make the gauge more useful by adjusting the voltage to the gauge to make it more representative of the battery voltage so that you can decide if it needs to be charged. The gauge is a two terminal device.

Figure 1. should represent your situation.

Am I correct?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuNexu.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Figure 2 shows a modification that uses the 9mA that the gauge draws. A series resistor with the gauge of the value shown will bring the voltage within range. 255\$\Omega\$ is not a standard value, but you may come close by combining values.

This will not indicate the charge state of the battery nor will the empty indication necessarily indicate the empty state of the battery. This will only adjust the displayed value so it will change when the battery voltage changes.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fK7USm.png)</sup>

If the above information does not represent the actual golf cart wiring, then you will have to provide more information. I am willing to rewrite my answer if my speculations are incorrect.

Comment: Yes, I computed I would need a 255 ohm resistor.  I have a [ lot ] of 1/4 watt resistors, I'm just a little short on 225 ohm 6 watt resistors.  lol [Edited by a moderator.]